# How can I create a token selling contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

How can I create a token selling contract, (I'm not sure of the correct term) that allows users to sell their tokens to it by send sending them to the contract address and receiving ETH back? I am fairly new to solidity, so forgive my lack of understanding, but I have the following code so far. Thanks.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

interface IERC20{
   
}

contract tokenBuyBack{

    IERC20 public token1;
    IERC20 public token2;
    address public owner1;
    address public owner2;

    constructor(address _token1, address _owner1, address _token2, address _owner2) public { 
        token1 = IERC20(_token1);
        token1 = _owner1;
        token2 = IERC20(_token2);
        owner2 = _owner2;
    }

    function swapA(uint256 amountA) {

        // Tranfer tokens from sender to this contract
        tokenA.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountA);

        // Calculate fees
        uint256 fee = amountA / 100; //1%
        uint256 amountB = amountA - fee;

        // Transfer amount minus fees to sender
        tokenB.transfer(msg.sender, amountB);
    }

}
```

Comment: You would need a big reserve of eth to do that and how are you going to get the equivalent if its changing all the time? I would say you need to check token swaps, look up uniswap for example, if you still think selling tokens is what you need let me know

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try to clarify better. I would be trying to swap one type of token with a preset price in ETH, no matter how many were bought. I believe the amount of ETH required for this particular token buy back would be doable, because its so cheap and there's very few holders and users expected to use the buyback. Ideally it would allow additional ETH to be sent to the contract and used for funds if it ran out, and if tokens are sent to the contract it sends the right amount of ETH back based on the preset price per token. Is this possible ?